# EnrichClient elasticsearch python API

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the python API for elasticsearch client in order to execute an existing enrichment policy.

In the API documentation there is an example with the `elasticsearch.client.EnrichClient` class, but when I'm trying to run python script with it I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 206, in transport return self.client.transport
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transport'
```

The command to elastic which I'm trying to run is: `es.execute_policy("overall_scoring_policy")`

Is there anyway I'm missing something with this type of client?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and managed to resolve it. Here is a working sample using the EnrichClient where I am executing a policy:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from elasticsearch import client
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# Configure variables for your environment
elasticUrl = 'https://cluster.contoso.foo:9200/'
requestTimeout = 60    # Request timeout in seconds
policyName = "Your_EnrichPolicy_Name"
apiId = "redactedId"
apiKey = "redactedKey"

# Create the Python Elasticsearch client
es = Elasticsearch(
  elasticUrl,
  api_key=(apiId, apiKey),
  request_timeout=requestTimeout,
  retry_on_timeout=True,
  max_retries=5
)

# Create the EnrichClient object using our Elasticsearch client object from above
enrichClient = client.EnrichClient(es)

# Execute the request and wait for completion
r = enrichClient.execute_policy(name=policyName, wait_for_completion=True)

# Print the response
print(str(r))
```